# Python Selenium, how to save http response content?

Tags: python, http, selenium

I want to automate such a process in selenium python.

On the webpage, there is a download button. After click the button, the server will sent back a text http response that browser would pop up a window to let me save.

In my python code, I have:

```
downBtn = browser.find_element_by_id('id')
```

I can then trigger downBtn.click(), browser will download the text file and save to default path. I'd like to get the content of the text file, save it with my new file name in some folder configured in my python script.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the browser (firefox ) preferences while creating your webdriver instance.

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",getcwd())
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv")

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

based out of info [here](http://watirmelon.com/2011/09/07/determining-file-mime-types-to-autosave-using-firefox-watir-webdriver/)

Comment: Thanks amey! It does download the file automatically. How can I rename the file before download?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot rename the file after downloading?

Comment: I want to download multiple files. If I change name after download, I have to make sure the file is downloaded. My code would like: downBtn.Click(), ChangeFileName(GetNewestFileInDir()) in a loop.

Comment: One question for you - Does the browser/OS not create unique file names while downloading the same/different files multiple times? My feeling is yes but I have not tried it out myself so was curios.